# creating a document with react-docx using uploaded .docx file

Tags: reactjs, docx

So I have a simple, single-page React app. I want to be able to let users drop an MS Word (.docx) file onto a dropzone and then let them download an edited version of their file.

I got the dropzone working and now can access the files in my JS code, and I'm trying to use [react-docx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-docx) to edit the document. It seems that this is a React version of [docx.js](https://docx.js.org/#/?id=welcome). However, I only see ways to create brand new documents, not any way to "load in" old ones for editing.

I don't want to start a document from scratch. Is there any way to make a new document using the file that is uploaded?

Anyone is appreciated who has expertise on this or just has a completely better idea for how to achieve my goal.

Comment: You need to find a parser for the file format, docx.js isn’t one (generating a subset of a data format is much easier than parsing any document written in a given data format … and docx is *very* complex).

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was afraid of that. Makes sense. I guess I may be looking at docxtemplater or something like that.

Comment: For any of those who view this question, what I had to do in the end was use docxtemplater (https://github.com/open-xml-templating/docxtemplater) to get plaintext from the Word file and then use another library to generate new Word documents. If I wanted to parse the Word document in any way (recognize paragraph breaks, etc.) I had to insert those by hand with a search/replace before dropping the document in for processing. Not elegant, but the app still saves a lot of people time so I guess it's okay.